# XPath. How to get element with next sibling of concrete type?

Tags: xpath, siblings, xpath-2.0, nextsibling

I have following elements:

```
<div>
  <table/>
  <div/>
  <table/>
  <div/>
  <table/> <!--I need to get only this one-->
  <table/>
  <div/>
</div>
```

So how to get //div/table with next element table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `//div/table[following-sibling::*[1][self::table]]`.